# Selector Tag for getting text value inside anchor tag

Tags: html, css-selectors

I need to select only text inside anchor tag ,
div.alphabetical-kategorie-entry a text --- doesn't works
div.alphabetical-kategorie-entry a   --- selects along with span element

```
<div class="alphabetical-kategorie-entry">
 <h2 class="">
  <a href="https://www.maceus.com/Agricultural-machinery/ci-4" class="">
   Agricultural machinery
  <span class="">348</span>
  </a>
 </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll(".alphabetical-kategorie-entry a").forEach(items=>console.log(items.innerHTML))   selects along with span tag

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question and adding the comment and the JavaScript tag, also if you could try to reword your question to make it clear what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain what it is that you are trying to do, but given your comment references JavaScript I'll assume it's something like this;

```
<div class="alphabetical-kategorie-entry">
  <h2 class="">
    <a class="" href="https://www.maceus.com/Agricultural-machinery/ci-4">
      Agricultural machinery
      <span class="">348</span>
    </a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

You'll need to give the anchor an Id.

Then access the text content using JavaScript as follows;

```
var x = document.querySelector("body > div > h2 > a").childNodes[0].textContent;
console.log(x);
```

Comment: This gives:  Agricultural machinery
      348

Comment: I  am looking to extract only Agricultural machinery not the text in span tag

Comment: Can we we do that without changing the structure

Comment: Can we get same thing using css Selector like div.alphabetical-kategorie-entry a    this gives text along with span element

Comment: var x = document.querySelector("body > div > h2 > a").childNodes[1].textContent; will return the span element text, is this what you mean?

Comment: Using JavaScript : document.querySelector("body > div > h2 > a").childNodes[1].textContent   we got the child elements .. can we get same thing using css selector ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean, I'm using a selector.

Comment: Please check the image am trying to select the text field -> first child from search panel based on css selector

Comment: I still don't know, do you mean this var x = document.querySelector("body > div > h2 > a > span").childNodes[0].textContent;